# how to redirect user to inbox of default SMS app from my iOS app using SMS API in ios8

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://"]];
```

I used this api to redirect user to default SMS app of ios but it creates a new message but what i dont want to create a new message but just want to show inbox of default SMS app. Is it possible using the above api in ios8.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html), you can only open the Messages app with

- the default "New Message" view ("sms:")
- the "New Message" view with a given phone number ("sms:1-408-555-1212")

=> The answer to your question is **NO**.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible. Apple never allows an app to access messages or receive messages, it can only send messages through their API. This is done for security purposes on the users behalf. They don't want app companies to be able to read user apps. The only good way to do messaging is to create your own messaging service using a database and you can link their phone number to the account so the user has to verify their phone number. This allows another user to enter their phone number and text them as if SMS, but instead it goes over the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your  suggestion regarding own messaging service.